# How do I scrape web content with BeautifulSoup when the response text doesn't have all the content that it's showing in my browser?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Using JupyterNotebook(ipynb), I'm trying to scrape web content with BeautifulSoup but the response text doesn't have all the content that it's showing in my browser. I'm trying to pull article titles and paragraph text but I'm unable to pull the paragraph text because it's not showing in my browser.

```
url = https://mars.nasa.gov/news/?page=0&per_page=40&order=publish_date+desc%2Ccreated_at+desc&search=&category=19%2C165%2C184%2C204&blank_scope=Latest
```

I went to the url in my browser and saw the content that I was looking for:

```
<div class="article_teaser_body">New evidence suggests salty, shallow ponds once dotted a Martian crater — a sign of the planet's drying climate.</div>
```

However, when I printed my response text, I do not see the content in there.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import os

url = 'https://mars.nasa.gov/news/?page=0&per_page=40&order=publish_date+desc%2Ccreated_at+desc&search=&category=19%2C165%2C184%2C204&blank_scope=Latest'

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

title = soup.find_all('div', class_='content_title')

# This outputs exactly what I need but when I try to do it 
# for the paragraph text (see below code), in outputs an empty list.

results = soup.find_all('div', class_='article_teaser_body')
```

The results list is empty

Comment: It is probably due the fact that those elements are javascript rendered, `requests` doesn't render javascript.

Comment: You can try [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Comment: I have posted the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58360455/3091398). Please do check and if it helped please accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use beautiful soup to scrape this url

```
https://mars.nasa.gov/news/?page=0&per_page=40&order=publish_date+desc%2Ccreated_at+desc&search=&category=19%2C165%2C184%2C204&blank_scope=Latest
```

When i check the network tab i found that this page is actually fetching article body using a JSON fetched from an API request which can easily be done using just `requests` library.

You can try the below code

```
import requests
import json # need to use this to pretty print json easily 

headers = {
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0' # to mimic regular browser user-agent
}

params = (
    ('page', '0'),
    ('per_page', '40'), # you tweak this value to 1000 or maybe more to get more data from a single request
    ('order', 'publish_date desc,created_at desc'),
    ('search', ''),
    ('category', '19,165,184,204'),
    ('blank_scope', 'Latest'),
)

# params is equivalent to page=1&per_page=40&order=publish_date+desc%2Ccreated_at+desc&search=&category=19%2C165%2C184%2C204&blank_scope=Latest

r = requests.get('https://mars.nasa.gov/api/v1/news_items/', params=params, headers=headers).json()

print(json.dumps(r, indent=4)) # prints the raw json respone

'''
The article data is contained inside the key `"items"`, we can iterate over `"items"` and 
print article title and body. Do check the raw json response to find 
other data included along with article title and body. You just need 
to use the key name to get those values like you see in the below code. 
'''

for article in r["items"]:
  print("Title :", article["title"])
  print("Body :",article["body"])
```

See this in action [here](https://repl.it/repls/InstructiveCarpalOpengl).